# Find changed position in 2 sorted JS objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

I have 2 JS objects with a `rank` and need to find the position that has changed.

```
// old data
var a = {
    0: {
        symbol: 'ABC',
        rank: '1'
    },
    1: {
        symbol: 'BCD',
        rank: '2'
    },
    2: {
        symbol: 'CDE',
        rank: '3'
    }
};

// new data
var b = {
    0: {
        symbol: 'BCD',
        rank: '1'
    },
    1: {
        symbol: 'ABC',
        rank: '2'
    },
    2: {
        symbol: 'CDE',
        rank: '3'
    }
};
```

The object `b` contains the same symbols as the object `a` and both are sorted by `rank`. I need to find all `symbols` with a new position.

In this example `a.0.symbol` and `b.0.symbol` have swapped their positions.

I'm looking for a solution to detect this change and get all `symbols` of object `b` with a higher position (key) than in object `a`.

```
higherRanked = ['BCD'];
```

Comment: please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically looping through `a` and `b` and finding the ones who got higher in the index.

```js
// old data
var a = {
    0: {
        symbol: 'ABC',
        rank: '1'
    },
    1: {
        symbol: 'BCD',
        rank: '2'
    },
    2: {
        symbol: 'CDE',
        rank: '3'
    }
};

// new data
var b = {
    0: {
        symbol: 'BCD',
        rank: '1'
    },
    1: {
        symbol: 'ABC',
        rank: '2'
    },
    2: {
        symbol: 'CDE',
        rank: '3'
    }
};

higher_ranked = []

Object.keys(b).forEach((b_index) => {
  const b_symbol = b[b_index].symbol 
  const a_index = Object.keys(a).find(index_a => a[index_a].symbol === b_symbol)
  if (b_index < a_index) higher_ranked.push(b_symbol)
})

console.log(higher_ranked)
// [ 'BCD' ]
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach can be to create a `symbol -> rank` mapping for objects in `a` and then filter keys in `b` that have a higher rank. Note that the index (key of the object) doesn't matter as you said they're both sorted by rank:

```js
var a = {
  0: {
    symbol: 'ABC',
    rank: '1'
  },
  1: {
    symbol: 'BCD',
    rank: '2'
  },
  2: {
    symbol: 'CDE',
    rank: '3'
  }
};

var b = {
  0: {
    symbol: 'BCD',
    rank: '1'
  },
  1: {
    symbol: 'ABC',
    rank: '2'
  },
  2: {
    symbol: 'CDE',
    rank: '3'
  }
};

var aRanks = Object.values(a).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.symbol] = parseInt(curr.rank);
  return acc;
}, {});

var higherRanked = Object.values(b)
                          .filter(s => parseInt(s.rank) < aRanks[s.symbol])
                          .map(s => s.symbol);
console.log(higherRanked);
```

This has time complexity *O(|a| + |b|)*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see this would work. It looks interesting, but at this point it's too complex for my level of understanding JS. I'm not sure if there would be a time advantage with your solution. Maybe I'll come back to this later and follow up on your answer.